# Unjustified high load averages

Tags: linux, centos, cpanel

I'm getting rather strange behavior in a new VPS system that i'm administering.
I hav ebeen facing this issue for around a month and i've tried everything in my power to find out what's causing it with no success.

specs:
cpu:dedicated 4 cores,
ram:10gb,
swap: 6gb,
vm.swappiness: 30,
OS: Centos 7.8,
Cpanel 90

I couldn't connect the "spikes"(up to 80) with any other behavior(user or server) and they're occuring randomly. Sometimes they are active for a few minutes other times for a couple of hours.

ps output:

```
Output from ps:
USER        PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
 root          2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep04   0:01 [kthreadd]
 root          4  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Sep04   0:00  \_ [kworker/0:0H]
 root          6  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep04   4:30  \_ [ksoftirqd/0]
 root          7  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep04   0:47  \_ [migration/0]
 root          8  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep04   0:00  \_ [rcu_bh]
 root          9  0.2  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep04 112:54  \_ [rcu_sched]
 root         10  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Sep04   0:00  \_ [lru-add-drain]
 root         11  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep04   0:29  \_ [watchdog/0]
 root         12  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep04   0:27  \_ [watchdog/1]
 root         13  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep04   0:56  \_ [migration/1]
 root         14  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep04   7:28  \_ [ksoftirqd/1]
 root         16  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Sep04   0:00  \_ [kworker/1:0H]
 root         17  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep04   0:32  \_ [watchdog/2]
 root         18  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep04   0:54  \_ [migration/2]
 root         19  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep04   5:12  \_ [ksoftirqd/2]
 root         21  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Sep04   0:00  \_ [kworker/2:0H]
 root         22  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep04   0:32  \_ [watchdog/3]
 root         23  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep04   0:47  \_ [migration/3]
 root         24  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep04   7:26  \_ [ksoftirqd/3]
 root         26  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Sep04   0:00  \_ [kworker/3:0H]
 root         28  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep04   0:00  \_ [kdevtmpfs]
 root         29  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Sep04   0:00  \_ [netns]
 root         30  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep04   0:01  \_ [khungtaskd]
 root         31  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Sep04   0:01  \_ [writeback]
 root         32  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Sep04   0:00  \_ [kintegrityd]
 root         33  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Sep04   0:00  \_ [bioset]
 root         34  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Sep04   0:00  \_ [bioset]
 root         35  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Sep04   0:00  \_ [bioset]
 root         36  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Sep04   0:00  \_ [kblockd]
 root         37  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Sep04   0:00  \_ [md]
 root         38  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Sep04   0:00  \_ [edac-poller]
 root         39  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Sep04   0:00  \_ [watchdogd]
 root         45  0.1  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep04  46:46  \_ [kswapd0]
 root         46  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   Sep04   0:00  \_ [ksmd]
 root         47  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   Sep04   0:07  \_ [khugepaged]
 root         48  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Sep04   0:00  \_ [crypto]
 root         56  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Sep04   0:00  \_ [kthrotld]
 root         58  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Sep04   0:00  \_ [kmpath_rdacd]
 root         59  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Sep04   0:00  \_ [kaluad]
 root         61  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Sep04   0:00  \_ [kpsmoused]
 root         63  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Sep04   0:00  \_ [ipv6_addrconf]
 root         77  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Sep04   0:00  \_ [deferwq]
 root        113  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep04   0:05  \_ [kauditd]
 root        253  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Sep04   0:00  \_ [ata_sff]
 root        254  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep04   0:00  \_ [scsi_eh_0]
 root        255  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Sep04   0:00  \_ [scsi_tmf_0]
 root        256  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep04   0:00  \_ [scsi_eh_1]
 root        257  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Sep04   0:00  \_ [mpt_poll_0]
 root        258  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Sep04   0:00  \_ [mpt/0]
 root        259  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Sep04   0:00  \_ [scsi_tmf_1]
 root        267  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep04   1:52  \_ [irq/16-vmwgfx]
 root        268  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Sep04   0:00  \_ [ttm_swap]
 root        275  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep04   0:00  \_ [scsi_eh_2]
 root        276  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Sep04   0:00  \_ [scsi_tmf_2]
 root        310  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep04  10:59  \_ [jbd2/sda1-8]
 root        311  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Sep04   0:00  \_ [ext4-rsv-conver]
 root        425  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Sep04   0:05  \_ [kworker/3:1H]
 root        426  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Sep04   0:07  \_ [kworker/0:1H]
 root        538  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Sep04   0:00  \_ [kdmflush]
 root        539  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Sep04   0:00  \_ [bioset]
 root        545  0.1  0.0      0     0 ?        R    Sep04  84:32  \_ [jbd2/dm-0-8]
 root        546  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Sep04   0:00  \_ [ext4-rsv-conver]
 root        552  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Sep04   0:00  \_ [kdmflush]
 root        553  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Sep04   0:00  \_ [bioset]
 root        560  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep04   2:25  \_ [jbd2/dm-1-8]
 root        561  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Sep04   0:00  \_ [ext4-rsv-conver]
 root        640  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Sep04   0:06  \_ [kworker/1:1H]
 root        868  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Sep04   2:20  \_ [loop0]
 root        870  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep04   0:15  \_ [jbd2/loop0-8]
 root        871  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Sep04   0:00  \_ [ext4-rsv-conver]
 root        976  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Sep04   0:07  \_ [kworker/2:1H]
 root      39821  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    20:30   0:00  \_ [kworker/1:2]
 root      48272  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    21:15   0:00  \_ [kworker/3:2]
 root      51294  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    21:32   0:00  \_ [kworker/3:1]
 root      51344  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    21:32   0:00  \_ [kworker/0:2]
 root      53041  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    21:42   0:00  \_ [kworker/u256:1]
 root      53483  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    21:45   0:00  \_ [kworker/2:1]
 root      54288  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    21:49   0:00  \_ [kworker/1:1]
 root      54724  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    21:51   0:00  \_ [kworker/2:0]
 root      55446  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    21:55   0:00  \_ [kworker/0:0]
 root      55448  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    21:55   0:00  \_ [kworker/u256:0]
 root      55930  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    21:59   0:00  \_ [kworker/3:0]
 root      55931  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    21:59   0:00  \_ [kworker/3:3]
 root      56120  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    22:00   0:00  \_ [kworker/2:2]
 root      56195  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    22:00   0:00  \_ [kworker/0:1]
 root      56286  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    22:00   0:00  \_ [kworker/u256:2]
 root          1  0.0  0.0 199580  3064 ?        Ss   Sep04  34:49 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --switched-root --system --deserialize 22
 root        391  0.0  0.5 121472 56420 ?        Ss   Sep04  18:00 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-journald
 root        413  0.0  0.0 264108     0 ?        Ss   Sep04   0:00 /usr/sbin/lvmetad -f
 root        420  0.0  0.0  44976    84 ?        Ss   Sep04   0:01 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
 root        582  0.0  0.0  55532   344 ?        S<sl Sep04   0:28 /sbin/auditd
 root        606  0.0  0.0  21688   476 ?        Ss   Sep04   2:23 /usr/sbin/irqbalance --foreground
 root        608  0.0  0.0  99688     0 ?        Ss   Sep04   0:00 /usr/bin/VGAuthService -s
 root        610  0.0  0.0  24544  1020 ?        Ss   Sep04   3:58 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-logind
 root        612  0.0  0.0 229640  1556 ?        Ss   Sep04  42:32 /usr/bin/vmtoolsd
 polkitd     613  0.0  0.0 612472  1096 ?        Ssl  Sep04   1:49 /usr/lib/polkit-1/polkitd --no-debug
 root        620  0.0  0.0  52872   384 ?        Ss   Sep04   0:00 /usr/sbin/smartd -n -q never
 dbus        621  0.0  0.0  58400  1124 ?        Ss   Sep04   9:25 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation
 rpc         637  0.0  0.0  69280    60 ?        Ss   Sep04   0:05 /sbin/rpcbind -w
 chrony      644  0.0  0.0 117808   656 ?        S    Sep04   0:07 /usr/sbin/chronyd
 root        677  0.0  0.0  25908   200 ?        Ss   Sep04   0:00 /usr/sbin/atd -f
 root        681  0.0  0.0 126420   380 ?        Ss   Sep04   0:29 /usr/sbin/crond -n
 root      56123  0.0  0.0 184932  1832 ?        S    22:00   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/CROND -n
 sfragi5   56139  0.0  0.1 474804 17736 ?        Ss   22:00   0:00  |   \_ /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/bin/php /home/sfragi5/public_html/wp-content/plugins/prisma_woocommerce_bridge/toprismawin.php
 mailnull  56170  0.0  0.0  77296  3576 ?        S    22:00   0:00  |   \_ /usr/sbin/sendmail -FCronDaemon -i -odi -oem -oi -t -f sfragi5
 root      56453  0.0  0.0 184928  2132 ?        S    22:02   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/CROND -n
 root      56457  0.0  0.0 113284  1200 ?        Ss   22:02   0:00      \_ /bin/bash -c /etc/nginx/utilities/https_vhosts.sh >> /dev/null 2>&1
 root      56460  0.0  0.0 113284  1404 ?        S    22:02   0:00          \_ /bin/bash /etc/nginx/utilities/https_vhosts.sh
 root      56463  0.0  0.0 108056   352 ?        S    22:02   0:00              \_ sleep 15
 root       1040  0.0  0.0 111436   272 ?        Ss   Sep04   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
 root      23305  0.0  0.0 159860  3208 ?        Ss   09:12   0:00  \_ sshd: sfragi5 [priv]
 sfragi5   23309  0.0  0.0 159992  2012 ?        S    09:12   0:33  |   \_ sshd: sfragi5@notty
 sfragi5   23311  0.0  0.0  70752  2124 ?        Ss   09:12   0:12  |       \_ /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
 root      23351  0.0  0.0 159860  3204 ?        Ss   09:12   0:00  \_ sshd: sfragi5 [priv]
 sfragi5   23354  0.0  0.0 159860  1720 ?        S    09:12   0:00  |   \_ sshd: sfragi5@notty
 root      56742  0.0  0.0 159860  3612 ?        Ss   11:39   0:00  \_ sshd: trikaliotis [priv]
 trikali+  56751  0.0  0.0 159860  2068 ?        S    11:39   0:02  |   \_ sshd: trikaliotis@notty
 trikali+  56753  0.0  0.0  70684  2024 ?        Ss   11:39   0:00  |       \_ /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
 root      56778  0.0  0.0 159860  3604 ?        Ss   11:39   0:00  \_ sshd: trikaliotis [priv]
 trikali+  56784  0.0  0.0 159860  1844 ?        S    11:39   0:00      \_ sshd: trikaliotis@notty
 root       1042  0.0  0.0 572396   756 ?        Ssl  Sep04   6:22 /usr/bin/python2 -Es /usr/sbin/tuned -l -P
 root       1049  0.0  0.2 655492 30148 ?        Ssl  Sep04  11:26 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n
 root       1327  0.0  0.2 116852 25720 ?        S    Sep04   7:45 cpsrvd (SSL) - waiting for connections                   
 root       1359  0.0  0.0 129452  2440 ?        Ss   Sep04   1:44 dnsadmin - dormant mode
 root       1429  0.0  0.0 129984  2700 ?        S    Sep04   1:59 cpdavd - accepting connections on: 2079, 2080, 2077, 2078 (dormant)
 root       1495  0.0  0.1  70196 14928 ?        S    Sep04  28:25 tailwatchd
 root       2245  0.0  0.0 151936  9916 ?        S    Sep04   2:24 cPhulkd - processor
 root      86596  0.0  0.0 151284  9388 ?        S    13:51   0:02  \_ cPhulkd - dbprocessor
 root      56438  0.3  0.1 152200 10996 ?        S    22:01   0:00  \_ cPhulkd - processor - http socket
 root       2574  0.2 11.3 1767700 1156936 ?     Ssl  Sep04 100:38 /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/clamd
 root       2597  0.0  0.0  45980  5800 ?        S    Sep04   2:02 queueprocd - waiting up to 60s to process a task
 named      8303  0.0  0.3 688152 36084 ?        Ssl  Sep04  25:57 /usr/sbin/named -u named -c /etc/named.conf
 nobody     8570  0.0  0.0  65792  4292 ?        SLs  Sep04   1:42 proftpd: (accepting connections)
 mysql    127998  7.2 26.3 8230512 2697084 ?     Ssl  Sep07 2950:40 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr
 mailnull 103686  0.0  0.0  80596  3456 ?        Ss   Sep17   2:06 /usr/sbin/exim -ps -bd -q1h -oP /var/spool/exim/exim-daemon.pid
 root      31932  0.0  0.0 108296   332 tty1     Ss+  Oct01   0:00 /sbin/agetty --noclear tty1 linux
 root      97502  0.0  0.0 225676  5600 ?        Ss   Oct01   1:39 /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 root      15919  0.0  0.0  12940   572 ?        S    Oct04   0:18  \_ /usr/local/cpanel/bin/splitlogs --dir=/etc/apache2/logs/domlogs --main=webhost.xpatit.com --suffix=-bytes_log
 root      15920  0.0  0.0  13136   876 ?        S    Oct04   0:20  \_ /usr/local/cpanel/bin/splitlogs --dir=/etc/apache2/logs/domlogs --main=webhost.xpatit.com --mainout=/etc/apache2/logs/access_log
 root      15925  0.0  0.0  53540  2996 ?        S    Oct04   0:00  \_ /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/perl /usr/local/cpanel/bin/leechprotect
 nobody    15927  0.0  0.0 225676  3116 ?        S    Oct04   0:02  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    50811  0.0  0.1 235148 13380 ?        S    21:28   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    51009  0.0  0.1 235124 13184 ?        S    21:29   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    51270  0.0  0.1 235148 12892 ?        S    21:31   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    51321  0.0  0.1 235044 12680 ?        S    21:32   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    51576  0.0  0.1 235248 13272 ?        S    21:33   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    51583  0.0  0.1 235152 13228 ?        S    21:33   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    51708  0.0  0.1 235248 13164 ?        S    21:34   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    51710  0.0  0.1 235172 13052 ?        S    21:34   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    51711  0.0  0.1 235124 13488 ?        S    21:34   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    51768  0.0  0.1 235144 13084 ?        S    21:34   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    51896  0.0  0.1 235144 12984 ?        S    21:35   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    52020  0.0  0.1 235252 13176 ?        S    21:36   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    52377  0.0  0.1 235036 12628 ?        S    21:38   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    52385  0.0  0.1 235120 13300 ?        S    21:38   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    52391  0.0  0.1 235132 13348 ?        S    21:38   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    52596  0.0  0.1 235320 13852 ?        S    21:39   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    52617  0.0  0.1 235132 12652 ?        S    21:39   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    52923  0.0  0.1 235116 13244 ?        S    21:41   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    53735  0.0  0.1 235120 13440 ?        S    21:46   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    53822  0.0  0.1 235116 12720 ?        S    21:47   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    53937  0.0  0.1 234980 12368 ?        S    21:47   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    53988  0.0  0.1 235168 13016 ?        S    21:48   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    54148  0.0  0.1 235312 12780 ?        S    21:48   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    54418  0.0  0.1 235116 12964 ?        S    21:49   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    54577  0.0  0.1 235116 13136 ?        S    21:50   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    54581  0.0  0.1 235040 11104 ?        S    21:50   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    54585  0.0  0.1 235036 12404 ?        S    21:50   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    54623  0.0  0.1 235040 12824 ?        S    21:50   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    54686  0.0  0.1 235032 12956 ?        S    21:50   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    54717  0.0  0.1 235168 13144 ?        S    21:51   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    54719  0.0  0.1 235032 12596 ?        S    21:51   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    54843  0.0  0.1 235032 11108 ?        S    21:51   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    54851  0.0  0.1 235028 12496 ?        S    21:51   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    55084  0.0  0.1 235036 12124 ?        S    21:53   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    55098  0.0  0.1 235036 12124 ?        S    21:53   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    55165  0.0  0.1 235028 12664 ?        S    21:53   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    55413  0.0  0.1 235036 12128 ?        S    21:54   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    55416  0.0  0.1 235036 12792 ?        S    21:54   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    55417  0.0  0.1 235024 12564 ?        S    21:54   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    55421  0.0  0.1 234904 10852 ?        S    21:54   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    55422  0.0  0.1 235036 12636 ?        S    21:54   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    55423  0.0  0.1 235036 12568 ?        S    21:54   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    55456  0.0  0.1 235296 13844 ?        S    21:55   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    55526  0.0  0.1 235032 12396 ?        S    21:55   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    55528  0.0  0.1 234900 12136 ?        S    21:55   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    55536  0.0  0.1 235036 11868 ?        S    21:55   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    55613  0.0  0.1 234904 10852 ?        S    21:56   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    55616  0.0  0.1 235036 12124 ?        S    21:56   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    55660  0.0  0.1 235004 12476 ?        S    21:56   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    55688  0.0  0.1 235036 12584 ?        S    21:57   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    55691  0.0  0.1 235004 12568 ?        S    21:57   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    55693  0.0  0.1 234980 12320 ?        S    21:57   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    55694  0.0  0.1 234900 12232 ?        S    21:57   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    55763  0.0  0.1 235292 13408 ?        S    21:57   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    55771  0.0  0.1 235164 13096 ?        S    21:57   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    55777  0.0  0.1 235040 12660 ?        S    21:57   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    55784  0.0  0.1 235036 11868 ?        S    21:57   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    55785  0.0  0.1 235036 12128 ?        S    21:57   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    55817  0.0  0.1 235116 12840 ?        S    21:58   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    55825  0.0  0.1 235032 12844 ?        S    21:58   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    55845  0.0  0.1 235036 12696 ?        S    21:58   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    55896  0.0  0.1 235036 12088 ?        S    21:58   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    55918  0.0  0.1 235200 12888 ?        S    21:58   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    56056  0.0  0.1 235028 12512 ?        S    21:59   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    56060  0.0  0.1 235036 11872 ?        S    21:59   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    56062  0.0  0.1 235036 12520 ?        S    21:59   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    56063  0.0  0.1 235036 12784 ?        S    21:59   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    56118  0.0  0.1 235036 12144 ?        S    21:59   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    56179  0.0  0.1 235140 13180 ?        S    22:00   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    56191  0.0  0.1 235184 13044 ?        S    22:00   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    56267  0.0  0.1 235032 12888 ?        S    22:00   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    56269  0.0  0.1 235032 12696 ?        S    22:00   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    56270  0.0  0.1 235112 12520 ?        S    22:00   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    56275  0.0  0.1 235028 12468 ?        S    22:00   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    56334  0.0  0.1 235032 12216 ?        S    22:01   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    56380  0.0  0.1 235040 12808 ?        S    22:01   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    56398  0.0  0.1 234900 11972 ?        S    22:01   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    56399  0.0  0.1 234904 10844 ?        S    22:01   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    56427  0.0  0.1 235032 12400 ?        S    22:01   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 nobody    56442  0.0  0.1 234900 12088 ?        S    22:01   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
 pavlousa  56472 10.5  0.3 246728 31004 ?        R    22:02   0:00      \_ /opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/bin/php-cgi /home/pavlousa/public_html/feeds/index.php
 root      97535  0.0  0.1 458336 11488 ?        Ss   Oct01   0:38 php-fpm: master process (/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/etc/php-fpm.conf)
 xpatitg   56250  2.7  0.4 477672 43560 ?        S    22:00   0:02  \_ php-fpm: pool xpatit_gr
 xpatitg   56441  1.0  0.2 461252 20864 ?        S    22:01   0:00  \_ php-fpm: pool xpatit_gr
 root      97541  0.0  0.0 340832 10124 ?        Ss   Oct01   0:30 php-fpm: master process (/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php-fpm.conf)
 wncc0m    56373  8.5  0.5 382100 53592 ?        S    22:01   0:03  \_ php-fpm: pool wnc_com_cy
 wncc0m    56400  4.1  0.5 382620 53756 ?        S    22:01   0:01  \_ php-fpm: pool wnc_com_cy
 root      97546  0.0  0.1 538208 13872 ?        Ss   Oct01   1:10 php-fpm: master process (/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/etc/php-fpm.conf)
 sfragi5   45460 38.8  2.6 1171204 270256 ?      S    20:59  24:13  \_ php-fpm: pool sfragidadiko_gr
 sfragi5   47299 34.3  2.8 1196284 294912 ?      R    21:09  18:02  \_ php-fpm: pool sfragidadiko_gr
 sfragi5   47305 33.3  2.4 1085912 254332 ?      S    21:09  17:33  \_ php-fpm: pool sfragidadiko_gr
 sfragi5   48028 27.6  2.3 1147960 244488 ?      R    21:13  13:21  \_ php-fpm: pool sfragidadiko_gr
 sfragi5   48162 34.4  2.9 1205580 300580 ?      S    21:14  16:22  \_ php-fpm: pool sfragidadiko_gr
 sfragi5   48551 30.7  2.4 1154032 250464 ?      R    21:17  13:52  \_ php-fpm: pool sfragidadiko_gr
 sfragi5   49072 33.1  2.3 1067204 238320 ?      S    21:19  14:10  \_ php-fpm: pool sfragidadiko_gr
 sfragi5   50251 37.3  2.6 1172980 272872 ?      R    21:25  13:36  \_ php-fpm: pool sfragidadiko_gr
 sfragi5   50938 31.8  3.6 1273292 372660 ?      R    21:29  10:30  \_ php-fpm: pool sfragidadiko_gr
 sfragi5   50941 29.4  2.6 1167088 268112 ?      S    21:29   9:43  \_ php-fpm: pool sfragidadiko_gr
 root      97553  0.0  0.1 466032 12728 ?        Ss   Oct01   0:23 php-fpm: master process (/opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php-fpm.conf)
 root      93863  0.0  0.0  15476   968 ?        Ss   Oct02   0:32 /usr/sbin/dovecot -F -c /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
 dovecot   93871  0.0  0.0  10172   612 ?        S    Oct02   0:12  \_ dovecot/anvil
 dovenull  15940  0.0  0.0  51448  5848 ?        S    Oct04   1:25  \_ dovecot/pop3-login
 dovenull  15941  0.0  0.0  49812  5024 ?        S    Oct04   0:03  \_ dovecot/imap-login
 root      15942  0.0  0.0  10304   584 ?        S    Oct04   0:14  \_ dovecot/log
 dovenull  15943  0.0  0.0  51588  5660 ?        S    Oct04   1:34  \_ dovecot/pop3-login
 dovenull  15944  0.0  0.0  49960  5012 ?        S    Oct04   0:04  \_ dovecot/imap-login
 root      15945  0.0  0.0  18768  2236 ?        S    Oct04   0:25  \_ dovecot/config
 dovecot   15946  0.0  0.0  44604  1888 ?        S    Oct04   0:14  \_ dovecot/stats
 dovecot   16151  0.0  0.0  10180   704 ?        S    Oct04   0:00  \_ dovecot/imap-hibernate
 dovecot  129145  0.2  0.0  71532  4520 ?        S    06:38   2:35  \_ dovecot/auth
 tlisis    55534  0.0  0.0  28924  2496 ?        S    21:55   0:00  \_ dovecot/quota-status -p postfix
 homeaid   55875  0.0  0.0  31360  3228 ?        S    21:58   0:00  \_ dovecot/pop3
 root      56245  0.0  0.0  70488  4096 ?        S    22:00   0:00  \_ dovecot/auth -w
 xpatitg   56406  0.1  0.0  38104  3856 ?        S    22:01   0:00  \_ dovecot/imap
 homeaid   56450  0.0  0.0  31360  3224 ?        S    22:01   0:00  \_ dovecot/pop3
 nscd      94243  0.0  0.0 1467644 2464 ?        Ssl  Oct02   1:33 /usr/sbin/nscd
 root      94460  0.0  0.0  26296  1596 ?        SN   Oct02   0:01 cpanellogd - sleeping for logs
 root      72201  0.0  0.1 117016 10308 ?        Ssl  Oct03   0:16 /usr/local/cpanel/base/frontend/paper_lantern/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.live.cgi -mode daemon
 root      71187  0.0  0.2 176700 28704 ?        Ss   00:00   0:48 lfd - sleeping
 root      56341  0.0  0.2 176832 28060 ?        S    22:01   0:00  \_ lfd - checking system integrity
 root      56343  1.8  0.0 108080   772 ?        D    22:01   0:01  |   \_ /usr/bin/md5sum --check /var/lib/csf/csf.tempint
 root      56476  0.0  0.2 176700 28204 ?        S    22:02   0:00  \_ lfd - (child) checking load...
 root      56477  0.0  0.0 153944  2148 ?        R    22:02   0:00      \_ /bin/ps axuf
 root      50476  0.2  1.1 242256 118512 ?       Ss   21:26   0:06 /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/perl/530/bin/perl -T -w /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/spamd --allowed-ips=127.0.0.1,::1 --max-children=5 --pidfile=/var/run/spamd.pid --listen=5 --listen=6
 root      51275  0.1  1.2 260120 129948 ?       S    21:31   0:02  \_ spamd child
 root      51276  0.0  1.2 258092 127900 ?       S    21:31   0:00  \_ spamd child
```

vmstat output:

```
Output from vmstat:
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
  r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 11  3 3146980 346748 425428 1995264    1    1   278   578    3    1 13  3 78  5  0
```

iostat output:

```
Linux 3.10.0-1127.19.1.el7.x86_64 (webhost.xpatit.com)  10/06/2020      _x86_64_        (4 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          14.01    0.55    3.11    5.39    0.00   76.94

Device:            tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn
sda              29.68       546.33       161.43 1496391757  442151272
sdb               4.41       226.98       283.95  621684425  777738548
sdc             199.94       333.97      1982.06  914743917 5428838668
sdd               1.10         4.59         5.70   12563012   15602768
dm-0            362.13       333.97      1982.06  914743409 5428838668
dm-1              4.50       226.98       283.95  621683917  777738548
```

in this particular case load averages where around 12(even for 15 minutes)

Comment: So you’re saying this is a VPS. Do you know how it’s hosted (KVM/OpenVZ/Xen/…)? Are you sure the physical host isn’t overloaded?

Comment: @Daniel The hypervisor is running vmware. I can't be sure it's not overloaded, however it comes from a very respectful local company and we are hosting another 10 systems with them with no issues. How can i make sure it's not overloaded?

Comment: You should run vmstat for more then 1 output as the first result is usually wildly inaccurate. Also monitoring "top" for a period can be helpful. Without some monitoring (like nagios + PNP ) we are shooting in the dark. How much swap does the VM have, how much is in use, and what is the value of VM.swappiness?